# Change Bootstrap 3 Carousel options on event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to instantiate the Bootstrap 3 carousel with one behavior, and then change that behavior on an event.

More specifically, the initial state of the carousel will cycle through all slides once with the following:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="500" data-wrap="false">
```

With the following jQuery I'm able to successfully fire an event after the carousel has ended it's cycle:

```
$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slid.bs.carousel',function() {
    if($(this).find('.item.active').is(':last-child')) {
        console.log('cycle ended');
    }
});
```

But if I update the above jQuery to be something like this:

```
$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slid.bs.carousel',function() {
    if($(this).find('.item.active').is(':last-child')) {
        $(this).data({
            interval: false,
            wrap: true
        });
    }
});
```

The carousel won't update it's behavior. I've tried variations of this using Bootstrap's `.carousel()` instead of `.data()` to set the initial and updated options (no data attributes used), but nothing has worked so far.

Is this even possible? How can I change the carousel's behavior after it's already been initiated?

Here's a Fiddle if that helps: http://jsfiddle.net/kvLmmyvm/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, and found the answer here:
[How to change interval of a bootstrap carousel once it has been initialised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271054/how-to-change-interval-of-a-bootstrap-carousel-once-it-has-been-initialised/30271506#30271506)

In short you can't seem to set new options, but you can find and edit the existing ones:

```
var opt = $(this).data()['bs.carousel'].options;
opt.interval = false;
opt.wrap = true;
```

In the linked answer they explicitly set the options back on the carousel `c.data({options: opt})` but I find it's not required.

Answer (score -1):

try it like this:

```
$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slid.bs.carousel',function() {
    if($(this).find('.item.active').is(':last-child')) {
        $(this).attr('data-wrap', true);
        $(this).attr('data-interval', false);
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**

here is the fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/w8mc0cge/

Comment: Thanks for the response, but no change.

Comment: I tried it on your fiddle link and then using inspect element and some logs it returns the right values. please check data-interval and data-wrap using inspect element again. also I should mention that doing these changes (data-wrap=true, data-interval=false) wouldn't have a visual effect as the slider is finished on last element.

Comment: The first line of my question clearly states that I'm looking to change the behavior of the carousel, not just the values of a data attribute.

Comment: ok but you didn't mention which behaviour you want to change! for example you can change interval time from 500 to 1000 like what I said above. data-interval= false  is not acceptable because it should contain a number not a boolean. please be more precise in your question to get a right answer!

Comment: From official Bootstrap 3 documentation re: data-interval: "The amount of time to delay between automatically cycling an item. If false, carousel will not automatically cycle."